# It "stopped working" when i run this code. I wish to call this simple function from the API

Tags: c++, api, crash

I just want to call the function from the API. WhozCraig just now told me that mine is just a type and not a function. But I still don't know how to solve this. How should i declare this instead of just typedef? Sorry, I'm a noob. Thanks for your help guys!

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ftrScanAPI.h"

typedef FTR_API_PREFIX FTRHANDLE (FTR_API *MyftrScanOpenDevice)();


MyftrScanOpenDevice NowftrScanOpenDevice;


void main()
{
FTRHANDLE hDevice=NULL;
PVOID pBuffer;
FTRSCAN_IMAGE_SIZE ImageSize;

hDevice=LoadLibrary("ftrScanAPI.dll");
if(hDevice==NULL)

{   printf("Failed to detect ScanAPI.dll");
    getch();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

hDevice = NowftrScanOpenDevice();
}
```

Here's a snippet from the API:

```
FTR_API_PREFIX FTRHANDLE FTR_API ftrScanOpenDevice();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `NowftrScanOpenDevice` is a pointer to a function, and as it's a global variable it's zero-initialized. By calling it, you are in effect dereferencing a `NULL` pointer, which is undefined behavior and leads to the crash.

You need to use [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the actual address of the function, and assign it to `NowftrScanOpenDevice`:

```
...
HMODULE hLibrary = LoadLibrary(...);

NowftrScanOpenDevice = (MyftrScanOpenDevice) GetProcAddress(hLibrary,
                                                            "ftrScanOpenDevice");

hDevice = NowftrScanOpenDevice();
...
```

Note: I added a new variable `hLibrary` for the handle returned by [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You need it to later call [`FreeLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683152%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! it solved everything. I owe you much! =D